# Installing heroku with brew not working. brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku

Tags: heroku, homebrew

When I run

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

I get this error

```
The following formula cannot be installed from bottle and must be built from source.   
heroku
```

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me now

```
curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```